# redirect users to a page and other user to another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, before-filter

I have two kinds of users: Workers and Admins.
I have a table of workers and a table of admins.
I want to force the user to sign in before he can enter to the application pages.
so I added אם my ApplicationController the next line:

```
`before_filter :authenticate_user!`
```

now, I wrote a function, is called: `is_worker` that check if the user is found in the workers table. if so, redirect him to the page of the workers. if the user isn't found, redirect him to the admin page.

I want that workers will not able to enter the admin pages, and the admins will not able to enter the workers pages.

so I think I should add: `before_filter :is_worker` to: `workerscontroller` and `adminscontroller`.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def is_worker
     @email = current_user.email
     tag = Worker.where(:email => @email)
     if tag.nil?
        redirect_to '/admins'
     else
        redirect_to '/workers'
     end
  end
end
```

please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: How are users and workers/admins related? Do you have a `User` class (table) and two separate `Worker`/`Admin` classes/tables? Or is it one class with a 'type' or 'role'? If you use devise you can do `authenticate_worker` and `authenticate_admin` if they are in separate tables.

Comment: @nathanvda, I am using 'devise'. I insert each user who signs up into workers table. I have a table of admins (I added my email into this table). I can make a worker to be a manager (by moving him from the workers table to the admins table). but, you told me that I can do: "authenticate_admin", but I have to define users to be admin. how can I define a user to be admin? and how to define a user to be a worker (in order to use: authenticate_admin and authenticate_worker)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very efficient. Assuming you're using STI, create an `is_worker?` method like this:

```
def is_worker?
  current_user.type == 'Worker'
end
```

Then in your controllers you can add a method like this:

```
def redirect_after_sign_in
  if current_user.is_worker?
    redirect_to '/admins'
  else
    redirect_to '/workers'
  end
end
```

I'd make it a private method. Then you can call this method after the user successfully logs in.

Even then you'll want to protect your application at the controller level so that a worker can't just go to the `/admins` URL and see admin data.

Comment: thank you.. and then I should add:
before_filter: is_worker
in the ApplicationController?

Comment: Actually I don't know what I was thinking suggesting this. Editing now.